# Rails Migration Change vs Up & Down methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I am working through the book Rails Test Prescriptions and during the setup it is asking me to change a migration file to the following:

```
class ProjectUserJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :projects_users, :force => true, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :project
      t.references :user
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :projects_users
  end
end
```

It seems I am using a later version on Rails (4.0.0) than the book (2 or 3.x) and my migration file looks like this:

```
class ProjectUserJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

How do I edit the change method to do the same as the up and down methods above? So far I have tried using up and down as opposed to self.up and self.down and copying in the same code. It did not work.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Now how should I write change to reflect the above up/down methods?

Comment: change should conatin what you put in up

Comment: the change method works like up/down at the same time, but I have errors while I use oracle as DB, so, I have to write up/down methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change `def change` with `def self.up` content.

You can check the result by running `rake db:migrate` at your console - it will create the table (self.up functionality) and `rake db:rollback` - it will drop the table (self.down functionality).

Answer (score 3):

Your `up/down` migration would look like this for `change`:

```
class ProjectUserJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects_users, :force => true, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :project
      t.references :user
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The change method is able to automatically figure out the down actions required based upon the create/update information you provide. It is not a complete replacement for the original self.up/self.down methods however as some database actions you take Rails is not able to automatically figure out what is the corresponding up/down actions.  On example of this is if you need to run an arbitrary SQL statement `execute-<<SQL ... SQL`.

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler to work with change, the migration should look like

```
class ProjectUserJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
    create_table :projects_users, :force => true, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :project
      t.references :user
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Up and down method is still valid to use but they call it

> old style of migration

. You might want to learn more about active record migration from [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-reversible)